# Looking for some scriptural verses which say that Lord Ganesha is tarpanapriya (fond of tarpana)

Tags: scripture, puranas, gods, ganesha, shloka

Most of us know that Lord Shiva is **Abhisekhapriya** or one who loves to be bathed. Similarly, Lord Vishnu is **Alankarapriya** or one who is fond of wearing ornaments.

Similarly, i know that Lord Ganesha is called **Tarpanapriya.** Or one who loves the act of Tarpana (the act of offering water through the Deva Tirthas on our hands).

It is believed that all the pains and sufferings of the universe reside in the belly of Sri Ganesha (this is something that i have been told by one of my Gurujis) and that's why its being depicted as so large. And, by doing Tarpana we remove those pains from His belly and thereby give him appeasement.

**I am looking for some Puranic verses which explicitly state Lord Ganesha as Tarpanapriya.**

*NOTE- Even only one verse will do.*

Comment: Do you want a scriptural verse that has the specific name Tarpanapriya, or any verse that says he's fond of or pleased by Tarpana?

Comment: I guess anyone will do @KeshavSrinivasan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [**BrihanNaaradeeya Puraanam, PoorvaBhaaga, Chapter 76**](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D-_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%83/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AD%E0%A5%AC)- it is clearly stated Ganesha is TarpanaPriya.

> दीपप्रियः कार्तवीर्यो मार्तण्डो नतिवल्लभः ।
>   स्तुतिप्रियो महाविष्णुर्**गणेशस्तर्णणप्रियः** ॥ ११५ ॥
>   दुर्गाऽर्चनप्रिया नूनमभिषेकप्रियः शिवः ।
>   तस्मात्तेषां प्रतोषाय विदध्यात्तत्तदादरात् ॥ ११६ ॥
>
> Deepa-Priyah Kaartaveeryo Maartando Nati-Vallabhah |
>   Stuti-Priyo MahaVishnur_**Ganeshas_Tarpana-Priyah** ||
>   Durgaa.rchana-Priyaa Noonam_Abhisheka-Priyah Shivah |
>   Tasmat_Teshaam Pratoshaaya Vidadhyaat_Tat_Tat_Aadaraat ||
>
> **Translation:**
>   Kartaveerya is fond of [**Deepa**](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5GpZ4l6rjj6O_0f6NQiFDwn-07Os19hNBgmGZTTyPijfvr1QjXFyCOs3FHA), Surya (Maartanda) endears [**Water Offering**](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSB_fQgqgdrWFqkfoJrTBl-OXAO_eiFLWt2AOTaKjruttKVRoUG4A)(Nati).
>   MahaVishnu rejoices [**Stuti**](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRwGjy41hBIPzt9XWCajXuxvUM92JD5vjTqBvf19fY5S49zqL5Un-dY7ibm)(Stotras et cetera or venerations done by devotees) and **Ganesha delights with** [**Tarpana**](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQogAAvvlvo2npPCNRmY_B8J_qkoRchYN4mmMrKKvPcO-hU2jG1MzQaZvQwRQ)(water libations).
>   Durga pleases with [**Prayers**](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTxjE8vGHBt4bhIiYdAXs7_Z1CYoOM_cmn_qAVE7W6QYuJveF8YwrzNAHPo)(Stotras et cetera, or Prayers said by Devotees) and Shiva likes being worshipped with [**Abhisheka**](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSDOftIf2DxofDvDIPbRYQQVzyp3Zd7OLyrlKI_RJYYezsN0jVsxheFRJTpxA)(bathing the deity by pouring water, milk, honey, Ghee, scented fluids, et cetera).
>   Thus, for Their satisfaction, one must fulfill Their worship with the above mentioned ways, with full respect and devotion.

Comment: Very nice find (such comments are likely to be deleted but still posting).